# yarn workspaces & monorepo & monobuild and how to build only what changed and dependencies?

Tags: yarn-workspaces

There are a few things done in monorepos/monobuilds (you can do a monorepo with no monobuild) that make things very nice but I don't see how yarn workspaces solves it just yet.  One of the main ones is I do not see how yarn workspaces can do this part of a mono build process (very typical for scale)

1. git status to figure out which files changed
2. map those files to projects that have changed
3. build those projects and projects that depend on those and projects that depend on those

I am a little confused there. As a monobuild scales up, we really desire build times of a server change is under 3 minutes and changes to a library that may affect all projects would take a long time as it builds the entire repo (unless we split it out to different machines and the build time goes way down again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think there is necessarily one answer here but a number of things to consider in the context of your project:

- If your project is really humungously large, consider someting like [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) which is a bit complex but allows for incremental building and testing.
- There are some specific tools to help with building large projects quickly. For instance, for JavaScript, there are [Turborepo](https://thenewstack.io/turborepo-speedy-builds-for-javascript-monorepos/) and [Nx](https://nx.dev/).
- [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces) or [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) can generally help with enabling better monorepo build processes by allowing us to run build scripts only for a subset of workspaces. They won't solve the problem though of figuring out what to build when, they just provide us with the basic building block of running scripts selectively.
- Finally a bit of Bash/Git/Makefile magic will probably be required. The following git command for instance can help us determine if files in particular paths have changed since the last commit `git diff --quiet HEAD~1 HEAD -- [paths]`. Note though this can can create a few annoying edge cases, especially if builds fail and we risk missing out on builing projects that we should build.
- There are plugins for some CI/CD platforms that wrap the Git commands in a somewhat easier to use way. For instance, I have used the GitHub action [has-changed-path](https://github.com/MarceloPrado/has-changed-path) and I think there was a plugin for BuildKite too, but I cannot find the link to that.

Generally I think it will be challenging to have a monorepo setup that avoids installing dependencies for all modules/workspaces and compiling all code. But I think it is possible to get to scale up to a few hundred thousand lines of code and hundreds of dependencies and keep install and compile times under 2-3 min using TypeScript in Yarn - when making good use of [TypeScript project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) and using something like [Yarn Zero Installs](https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs).

Comment: thanks, the detail you added in your answer is much appreciated!